# In GCP Load Balancer, How Can I Implement WildCard Paths In Load Balancers

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-load-balancer

See the image below of me trying to implement wildcard paths to route to a different backend:

[image]

If I enter a path such as `/events/*`, its allowed for routing to a different backend. But if I try to get more specific such as `/events/*/upload`, it does not work.

I am trying to have all media (video, images, etc) be processed on a different backend, and my route will have a UUID and look something like `/events/1234-323442-f234-3-/upload`. How can I route that to a different backend?

Comment: Did you notice this section? Do you use a classic HTTPS load balancer? https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map-concepts#wildcards-regx-dynamic

Answer (score 1):

Per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map-concepts#pm-constraints):

> - A path rule can only include a wildcard character (*) after a forward slash character (/). For example, /videos/* and /videos/hd/* are valid for path rules, but /videos* and /videos/hd* are not.
> - Path rules do not use regular expressions or substring matching. PathTemplateMatch can use simplified path matching operators. For example, path rules for either /videos/hd or /videos/hd/* do not apply to a URL with the path /video/hd-abcd. However, a path rule for /video/* does apply to that path.
> - Path matchers (and URL maps in general) do not offer features that function like Apache LocationMatch directives. If you have an application that generates dynamic URL paths that have a common prefix, such as /videos/hd-abcd and /videos/hd-pqrs, and you need to send requests made to those paths to different backend services, you might not be able to do that with a URL map. For simple cases containing only a few possible dynamic URLs, you might be able to create a path matcher with a limited set of path rules. For more complex cases, you need to do path-based regular expression matching on your backends.